# How to solve the following periodic ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and  $y$ is a $\pi-$periodic function

how we can solve the following ODE

$$y(x)\sin(x)-y^{'}(x)\cos(x)=a\sin(x)$$

what I have try:

I take $Y(x)=y(x)\cos(x)$ this gives $Y^{'}(x)=-a \sin(x)$ so $Y(x)=a \cos(x)+C$
this implies $y(x)=a+\frac{C}{\cos(x)}$ I am little confused about this solution (if I put $y(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$ this solution will be note defined )

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Y(x)=(-cos(x)y(x))$, so it holds that $$Y'(x)=sin(x)y(x)-cos(x)y'(x)$$
That means $$ Y'(x)=asin(x)$$
And hence $$Y(x)=-acos(x)+ cst$$
Therefore $$y(x)=a-\frac{cst}{cos(x)}$$ of course whenever $x\neq \pi/2+k \pi$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks @AlphaXY as far as I know the solution should be $C^{1}$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes so you can take its derivative